# Djagno rest view file structure with complex calculations

Tags: python, django, forms, rest

I'm writing django rest api. I'll be taking form which will be sent from frontend.
Form will contain data which I'll be using for performing calculation. But there is a problem. Based on form data code should execute different calculation types.
So for example
form

```
{
"type": 1,
"form": 3,
"method": 4
... more data
}
```

Then I should read "type". It should lead rest of form to another View method called for example type1. Then using "form" it should go for another view method form3 etc. Should I write that long api views methods or maybe I should create another file for performing calculations based on form data? The calculations methods are really different so it is not possible to base it on one method and multiple ifs.

Example (I will not attach serializer validation etc there):

```
class SubmissionView(APIView):
  def post(self, request):
    if request['type'] == 1:
       self.type1(request.data)
    elif request['type'] == 2:
       self.type2(request.data)
........

  def type1(self, request_data):
    if request['form'] == 1:
       self.form1(request.data)
    elif request['form'] == 2:
       self.form2(request.data)
 etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your problem. But if you just want to simplify your code I suggest that

Create a dictionary to map methods based on your form inputs like this:

```
class SubmissionView(APIView):

    function_map = {
       "1" : { # Is the type 1
          "1" : { # Is the form 1
             "1" : self.my_fun_a, # Is the method 1
             "2" : self.my_fun_b  # Is the method 2
          },
          "2" : { # Is the form 2
             "1" : ...,
             "2" : ...
          },
        }
        ...
    }

   def post(self, request):
      
       type_value   = request['type']   # make sure it's string
       form_value   = request['form']   # make sure it's string
       method_value = request['method'] # make sure it's string
       data1        = request['data1']
       data2        = request['data2']
       # ...

       if type_value in self.function_map.keys():

          type_map = function_map[type_value]

          if form_value in type_map.keys():

              form_map = type_map[form_value]

              if method_value in form_map.keys():

                 my_method = form_map[method_value]

                 # Call method here
                 return Response( my_method(data1, data2, ...) )

              else:
                # error
          else:
            # error
       else:
         # error

    def my_fun_a(self, *args, **kwargs):
       # Compute
       return result

    def my_fun_b(self, *args, **kwargs):
       # Compute
       return result
```

Or

```
function_path_map = {
   # "type/form/method"
   "1/1/1" : self.my_fun_a,
   "1/1/2" : self.my_fun_b,
   ...
}

...

method_path = f"{type_value}/{from_value}/{method_value}"

if method_path in self.function_path_map.keys():
   self.function_path_map[method_path](data...)
```